# React slick creating a weird white space on the right side of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

I have had this problem for a while now and it seems to affect all my pages. After commenting all my components, I found that the problem only appears after using react slick. I couldn't find any extra padding or margin on any element from the inspect, yet the whole page scrolls some pixels to the left and leaves a white space from top to bottom of the whole page especially on Chrome and Opera.
[image: This is the white space]

I tried to add custom CSS to the generated classes to force the widths to `100vw, 100%` also used `!important` did the same to `body` tag, `padding: 0; margin: 0` but the problem still persisted. Also tried to change the `settings` on the slider to see whether it was caused by some of the parameters but still no change. so I recreated a simple version of the problem on Code Sandbox

[Full code on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slick-space-problem-kxp6bj?file=/src)

My CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  width: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.app-slider-div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #272727;
}

.app-slider-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.app-slider-div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

My Component

```
import "./styles.css";

import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default function App() {
  const settings = {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app-slider-div">
          <div className="app-slider-title">App Slider Image</div>
          <div className="app-slider-content">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656925368663-f7e9cfb9c466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
              alt="app slider"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any solution to remove the white space will be appreciated

Comment: If you don't want to use arrows, just make them false in the JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to remove the Button right style

```
.slick-next {
    right: 0;
}
```

**Or**

Add **arrows:false** in slick slider js

Comment: Yeah, it seems it is, and I recommend setting a box-sizing property to a border-box model because it looks weird now, and if the author wants, add gaps between items using slick property

Comment: Both solutions worked for me, Thanks